# The Collatz Conjecture function should induce a collection of Grothendieck groups, one for each $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{N}$. Their properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, collatz-conjecture, open-problem, grothendieck-construction

This question is about the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Let $\Bbb{N}$ include $0$. The Collatz conjecture function is given by:
$$
f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}, \\
f(n) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{n}{2}, \text{ if } n = 0 \pmod 2,\\
\dfrac{3n + 1}{2}, \text{ if } n = 1\pmod 2 \text{ and } n \gt 1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, break up the conjecture into an infinite number of cases, one for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ as is what usually happens when mathematicians collectively attack problems.  The result is a proven special cases section on the conjecture's Wikipedia page.

We can also extend $f$ to $\Bbb{Z}$ as is and get several all-negaive value loops.

Anyway, let the domain and range space be $\Bbb{N}$ for now.  We know that $\Bbb{N}$ forms a commutative monoid under addition.  Define the equivalence relation:

Fix $n \in \Bbb{N}$.  Define the equivalence relation on $\Bbb{N}$:

$$
i\sim j \iff f^i(n) = f^j(n)
$$

Then $i\sim j, i' \sim j' \implies$ $i + i' \sim j + j'$ so that the equivalence relation respects $+$ on $\Bbb{N}$.

Then you can form a congruence monoid $N = \Bbb{N} / \sim$.  For example for $n = 1$ this is $f^0(1) = 1$, $f^1(1) = 2$, $f^2(1) = 1, \dots$ so that the equivalence classes are $2 \Bbb{N}$ and $2\Bbb{N} + 1$.

Therefore we say that the Collatz conjecture induces the group $\Bbb{Z}/2 = G(M/\sim) = $ the Grothendieck group of $\Bbb{N}/\sim$.

That makes perfect sense!  There's a loop of "length 2" there namely $(1,2,1,2,1,\dots)$ where entries are iterate values $f^i(1), i \geq 0$ (so the entries are $0$-based indexed).

> Therefore, I reckon that the Grothendieck groups $G(\Bbb{N}/\sim_{n})$ where $\sim_n$ means $n$ is the input to $f^i(n)$ in the definition of $\sim$ must have some property that flags whether or not $n$ gives an example to the conjecture, is there?

I don't think it's finiteness.  For example $n$ terminating at $1$ gives a finite group as well as $n$ going off and then self-looping somewhere else would give a finite group.

---

**Further Attempt.**

The $f^i(n)$ sequence can either shoot off to infinity, self-loop somewhere (here at $i = 0$ or further at $i = x \gt 0$), or it can drop back down to a value $m \lt n$.  In the first case we have that $G_n := G(\Bbb{N}/\sim_n)$ is trivial.  In the second case we have:

$$
n, n_1, n_2, \dots, n_j, n_{j+1}, \dots, n_{k-1}, n_k = n_j, n_{j+1}, \dots
$$

for some $n_k \gt n_{j} \geq n$.  And in the third case we have:

$n, n_1, n_2, \dots, n_{k-1}, n_{k} = 2, 1, 2, 1, \dots$ for some $k \gt 0$, since by induction on $n$ we've handled all cases $m \lt n$ and they go to the 1-2 loop.

The Grothendieck group in the second case is that of the monoid:

$$
\{[0], [1], [2], \dots, [j-1], [j],[j+1], \dots, [k-1] \}
$$

> What is the Grothendieck group isomorphic to in this case?

Comment: @MartinR I thought you could do $$f^{i+i'}(n) = f^{i}(f^{i'}(n)) = f^{i}(f^{j'}(n)) = f^{i + j'}(n) = f^{j'}(f^{i}(n)) = f^{j'}(f^{j}(n)) = f^{j+j'}(n)$$

Comment: I previously gave some consideration to what you describe and found it of interest that the known cycles over the integers carry the structure of the dihedral group $D_{14}$.  I had a hunch it was *Grothendieck groups* at play - something about which I know very little.  I wanted to quotient out the group and see what remained but to do so was way beyond me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we might want to note that there is nothing special about the Collatz function used for the construction here. In fact, we can even look at any function $f: X \to X$ for any set $X$ and construct an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{N}$ for any $x \in X$ just the way you did. You are effectively describing the equivalence relation defined by the fibres of $\varphi_{f,x}: \mathbb{N} \to X, i \mapsto f^{i}(x)$.

There are essentially two possibilities, either there exist some distinct $i$ and $j$ such that $f^i(x) = f^j(x)$  or there don't (i.e. $\varphi_{f,x}$ is injective). In the latter case $\sim$ is trivial and $G(\mathbb{N}/\!\sim) \:\cong G(\mathbb{N}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. You wrote that this case would give a trivial Grothendieck group but that is actually not the case, a trivial Grothendieck group corresponds to one of the $f^i(x)$ being a fixed point (this follows from what is following).

The other option is to have $f^{i}(x) = f^{j}(x)$ for some distinct $i$ and $j$. Let us assume $i < j$ and that $j$ is minimal, so that $f^{0}(x),f^{1}(x),\dots, f^{j-1}(x)$ are the distinct values of $\varphi_{f,x}$.

The Grothendieck group $G(\mathbb{N}/\sim)$ is thus finite and moreover cyclic since $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ is generated by the equivalence class of $1$.

Since $i \sim j$ we have $j - i = 0$ in $G(\mathbb{N}/\sim)$. It turns out that  $G(\mathbb{N}/\sim)$ is cyclic of order $j - i$. In fact, if we had $m = 0$ in
$G(\mathbb{N}/\sim)$ for some $0 < m < j -i$, then $m + k = k$ in $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ for some $k$, in other words $f^{m + k}(x) = f^{k}(x)$. After using $f^{i}(x) = f^{j}(x)$ multiple times, this gives $f^{r}(x) = f^{s}(x)$ for some $r < s < j$ which contradicts the minimality of $j$.

Finally, for the Collatz Conjecture, note that the orbit $1,2,1,\dots$ of length two is actually the only orbit of length two occuring for the Collatz function $f$. Thus $n$ satisfying the Collatz conjecture is equivalent to $G(\mathbb{N}/\sim_{n})$ being cyclic of order two.

Comment: Still digesting the rest of your answer but assuming what you say is true, the trivial Grothendieck group(s) can still be recovered by using $mj$ and $mi$ in place of $i$ and $j$, or equivalently substituting $f^m(x)$ for $f(x)$ where $m$ is the order of the cycle.

Comment: On another note, I have previously looked at the cyclicity of known fibers over the integers, and these have the symmetries of the dihedral group $D_{14}$. Do you think analysing this structure perhaps offers hope of finding an algebraic underpinning of the conjecture?

Comment: @samerivertwice I am not sure I understand you comments completely, but this might simply come from the fact that I am not very familiar with the conjecture. Yes, if $m$ is the order of the cycle then the Grothendieck group $G$ is cyclic of order $m$ so $mG$ is trivial, but what do you mean by 'recovering' trivial Grothendieck groups? Also, how do you obtain a non-cyclic group via this construction or is this something else you are doing? As I said, I don't know much about the conjecture, so I don't think I can give you an answer to your question that would be anything more than a guess.

Comment: @samerivertwice this is probably not the only associated group.  I just called it "the Grothendieck group" thinking it was something significant, but it probably isn't.  By that I mean, we still have to figure out how to prove the conjecture!  Perhaps it can be used but later on...

Comment: You wrote in your answer: *You wrote that this case would give a trivial Grothendieck group but that is actually not the case...*  By "recovering" I simply mean this: Where it is *not* the case, it **is** the case if you use $f^m(x)$ instead, that is all.

Comment: As regards arriving at something other than a cyclic group, I meant this: in $\Bbb Z/\langle2\rangle$, we have the following known cycles: $-1, 0, 1$ are fixed points.  $(-5,-7)$ is a cycle and so is $(-17,-25,-37,-55,-41,-61,-91)$.  So you may be able to imagine that exchanging $-5$ and $-7$ is like reflecting a septagon over, while rotating through the cycle of $7$ is like rotating the septagon, so it has the symmetry of the dihedral group $D_{14}$

Comment: @samerivertwice I hope you can excuse my confusion, but I am struggling following your line of thought. Regarding $\mathbb{Z}/ \langle 2 \rangle$, are you talking about the cyclic group of order $2$? Because this one has only $2$ elements and I fail to see how you would get any of the fixed points or cycles you mention, especially since the Collatz function does not induce a map on this group. Could you clarify this?

Comment: No, not the group. I'm simply referring to the set $\Bbb Z$ reduced by the equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff\exists i\in\Bbb Z:2^ix=y$ in other words just let every odd number represent itself multiplied by any whole power of two of your choosing.  So e.g. $3\sim6\sim12\sim24...$  It's a common way of looking at the conjecture.

Comment: I see, then it was just the notation I was confused with. However, I would argue that your geometric interpretation is not on point. You are more likely looking at a group $C_2 \times C_7 \cong C_{14}$, cyclic of order $14$.

Comment: I guess if we take the accelerated Collatz map $f(x) = |3x + 1|_2(3x + 1)$.  Where $|\cdot|$ is $2$-adic abs value, that the conjecture is true iff $G(\Bbb{N}/\sim) \simeq 1$ the trivial group.

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics I believe the accelerated Collatz map is usually only defined on the set of odd integers. But apart from that this is essentially true, because the only fixed point of the accelerated Collatz map is $1$: In fact, if $x$ is an odd number which is a fixed point, then $3x+1 =  2^k x$ and so $x$ divides $3x+1$ which implies $x = 1$.